# Unable to locate element using selenium Python

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to enter information into the input fields using Selenium in Python. I am having trouble finding the expiration date and CVV fields. I know they are in iframes but I was only able to input the credit card number correctly.  Everything else was empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.audiobooks.com/signup")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("1234567890987654")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='expirationDate' and @id='expirationDate']"))).send_keys("11/21")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-cvv']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='cvv' and @id='cvv']"))).send_keys("123")
```

the url I am using is: https://www.audiobooks.com/signup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch to next iframe you need to switch back to main DOM first. So just add below code between frame-switching lines:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Your final code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='number' and @id='credit-card-number']"))).send_keys("1234567890987654")

driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='expirationDate' and @id='expiration']"))).send_keys("11/21")

driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-cvv']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='cvv' and @id='cvv']"))).send_keys("123")
```

Comment: expiration date and cvv are still empty

Comment: @Recidivist , yeap, your locator was not correct: you need `@id='expiration'` instead of `@id='expirationDate'`. Try updated code